# Harmonic Function with linear growth

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

We want to find harmonic functions $w$ in (say) $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are zero on $\{y=0\}$ with the linear growth bound
\begin{equation} \sup_{\mathbb{B}_R} |w| \leq C(1+R)
\end{equation}
where $C>0$ independent of $R$, are the only solutions to such a problem $w(x,y)=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

I cannot think of a method to even start this at the moment as the usual tools (like mean value property or Harnack) do not seem to give anything of use. I feel like it is possible an application of Harnacks inequality in a clever way might do it?

Comment: Poisson integral. Use that to see that $w$ must be linear.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see how this would give us that $w$ must be linear, could you elaborate?

Comment: Show that all second partial derivatives vanish identically.

Comment: I understand the idea but could you show how to properly prove that the x partials vanish identically I cannot seem to deduce this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball) for balls with centre $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by

$$P(x,\zeta) = \frac{1}{\lVert\zeta\rVert\omega_{n-1}} \cdot \frac{\lVert\zeta\rVert^2 - \lVert x\rVert^2}{\lVert \zeta - x\rVert^n},$$

and for any function $u$ harmonic on the open ball with radius $R$ and continuous on the closed ball, in particular for entire harmonic functions, we have the integral representation

$$u(x) = \int_{\lVert\zeta\rVert = R} u(\zeta)P(x,\zeta)\,d\sigma(\zeta)$$

for $\lVert x\rVert < R$, where $\sigma$ is the surface measure on the boundary sphere.

All partial derivatives of $u$ can then be obtained by differentiating under the integral, i.e.

$$D^\alpha u(x) = \int_{\lVert\zeta\rVert = R} u(\zeta)D_x^\alpha P(x,\zeta)\,d\sigma(\zeta)$$

for every multi-index $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

For any compact $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the Poisson kernel is asymptotically equal to $\dfrac{1}{\omega_{n-1}\lVert\zeta\rVert^{n-1}}$ as $\lVert\zeta\rVert\to\infty$, uniformly on $K$. Differentiating with respect to $x$, one verifies that $D_x^\alpha$ is asymptotic to

$$C_{\alpha}\cdot \frac{1}{\lVert\zeta\rVert^{n-1+\lvert\alpha\rvert}}$$

uniformly on $K$. Thus if we have a growth restriction

$$\lvert u(x)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot \lVert x\rVert^k$$

for $\lVert x\rVert \geqslant R_0$, we find

$$\lvert D^\alpha u(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_{\lVert\zeta\rVert = R} C\lVert\zeta\rVert^k \frac{C_\alpha}{\lVert\zeta\rVert^{n-1+\lvert\alpha\rvert}} \,d\sigma(\zeta) \leqslant \tilde{C}\cdot R^{k-\lvert\alpha\rvert}$$

for $x\in K$ and all $R\geqslant R_0$. If $\lvert\alpha\rvert > k$, then letting $R\to\infty$ shows that $D^\alpha u \equiv 0$ on $K$. If $K$ has non-empty interior, the real analyticity of harmonic functions implies that $D^\alpha u \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Letting $\alpha$ run through all multi-indices of order $k+1$ then shows that $u$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant k$, since all partial derivatives of order $k+1$ vanish identically.

Here, we have a bound with $k = 1$, so $w$ must be a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 1$. The condition that $w(x,0) = 0$ forces the constant term and the $x$ term to vanish, so $w(x,y) = a\cdot y$ for some $a$.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, if you don't mind I have a question on this one. I wanted to prove: $u(x)=k \cdot x$ for a constant vector $k$ if the harmonic function $u$ satisfies $|u(x)| \leq C |x|$ for some $C >0.$ The question I have is what does the notation $\omega_{n-1}$ stands for ? The Poisson kerentl I'm accustomed to is the one with 
$$P(r,\theta)=\frac{|a|^2 - r^2}{|a-r|^2},$$
with an apparent direct extension. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Fib1123 $\omega_{k}$ is the ($k$-dimensional) measure of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$. The most important part of the Poisson kernel is the $\dfrac{\lVert \zeta\rVert^2 - \lVert x\rVert^2}{\lVert \zeta - x\rVert^n}$, but we need a normalisation factor so that the integral over the sphere with radius $R$ comes out as $1$. Now $$\int_{\lVert\zeta\rVert = R} \frac{\lVert\zeta\rVert^2-0^2}{\lVert\zeta - 0\rVert^n}\,d\sigma(\zeta) = R^{2-n} \int_{\lVert\zeta\rVert = R}d\sigma(\zeta) = R^{2-n}\cdot \omega_{n-1}R^{n-1} = \omega_{n-1}R.$$

Comment: So we must divide by the measure of the unit sphere, and the radius of the sphere. But the radius must be expressed in terms of the arguments of the kernel, so we must write it as $\lVert\zeta\rVert$, which leads to $$P(x,\zeta) = \frac{1}{\omega_{n-1}\lVert\zeta\rVert}\frac{\lVert\zeta\rVert^2 - \lVert x\rVert^2}{\lVert \zeta - x\rVert^n}.$$ For balls with centre $c \neq 0$, $\zeta$ must be replaced with $\zeta - c$.

Comment: @Fib1123 Yes. (Side remark: the symbol $k$ appears in way too many different roles here, it took me a while to figure which $k$ you meant :-) Estimating the twice differentiated Poisson integral shows all second derivatives vanish, and since $\lvert u(x)\rvert \leqslant C\lvert x\rvert$ shall hold for all $x$, the constant term of $u$ is $0$.