# Show that a given harmonic function has a specific form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Suppose $u$ is a harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfies 
$$|u(x)| \leq C |x|~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
Show that $u(x)=q \cdot x$ where $q$ is a constant vector.

I'm struggling with this problem. I tried defining a new function, $v(x)=u(x)/{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and using the given bound $C,$ that leads to a constant vector.  Being dividing by a vector, that couldn't be correct. My gut feeling says that this could be done using Maximum principle. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is a solution here; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285472/harmonic-function-with-linear-growth

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, thank you. I went through it. I didn't expect that much technical detail in the proof. That's the first time I saw an argument like that.

Comment: If you already know about Cauchy estimates, you can use those directly to show that the derivatives vanish. The solution linked above basically rederives those estimates.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong, thank you.  I know Cauchy estimate to apply in Complex analysis problem, not here though. I'm still struggling to come up with a good proof.

Comment: The Cauchy estimate is nearly the same in this context. For a real harmonic function $u$ in an $n$-dimensional domain, $|D^{\alpha} u(x_0)| \le C_{\alpha} r^{-n-k} \|u\|_{L^1(B)}$, where $\alpha$ is a $k$-multi-index and $B$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$. To prove this, you basically use the mean value property and differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Because $u$ is harmonic, it is real analytic, and so it can be uniformly approximated in some large open ball by a high-degree polynomial. Deduce that most of the polynomial's coefficients are zero.

Comment: thank you. I'll see along your suggestion. So this doesn't rely on any PDE argument, like Maximum principle ?

Comment: @ManMath You might be able to use the maximum principle, this was just the first thing that came to mind. There are quite a lot of ways that you can do this. You can think of harmonic functions as implying a lot about the growth of the derivatives of the function. For example, applying Cauchy estimates on the derivatives would also work to show that the function cannot have higher-order terms.

Comment: I see. This is a familiar problem in many mathematics subfields.